# the command "docker-machine ls " list nothing on my mac

Tags: macos, docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

I installed the latest stable docker for Mac, and started the docker directly without a virtual box. I know that it must have started a virtual box, so I use "docker-machine ls" to find the default machine, but it list nothing. How can i find the virtual machine? My OS version is 10.10.5
PS:
In fact, I didn't create any virtual machines, but do run my spring-boot app on the "alpine-oraclejdk8" image, so does that mean I exactly using the docker? And the reason I want to find the virtual machine is I used "nsenter" to enter the container to debug the log of my app but it doesn't work(the writer of "nsenter" told that I need enter the virtual machine first). So this is my confusing point that how the docker is running but I cant find the virtual machine on MAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker for mac does not use docker-machine. The app that runs and give you the little whale icon in the top menu bar runs its own virtual machine. This virtual machine uses hyperkit, which is a project that uses xhyve, which is a port of bhyve to the mac os darwin kernel.

This will not create any entries to make docker-machine aware of the vm.

Rather than using `nsenter` to enter your container, you should use the `docker exec` command instead. The advantage of using `docker exec` is that it works without having the first ssh to where docker is running.

Comment: YEAH, I also find the explain in official DOC ..thanks a lot. For the point of how to enter the container is that I deployed my app to the "alpine-oraclejdk8:slim" image which  does not have bash. I don't know what I can do without bash if I just use docker exec or docker attach to enter the container .That's why I choose "nsenter".....finally I had to install a virtualbox with boot2docker and connect docker to the machine....T T

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to create it.

Run the command

```
docker-machine create vm1
```

And you'll have your machine.

To redirect your docker client to the specific machine use this command

```
eval $(docker-machine env vm1)
```

Where 'vm1' is the same 'vm1' name that you used to create the machine.  You can have a number of docker machine running at the same time using various backends like virtualbox or aws

Comment: every machine created by docker-machine will be running docker host.  The docker command will connect to the machine you select.

Comment: but it's so weird that I started the docker first, then create a virtual-machine...so can docker run on mac  BEFORE I create a virtual-machine?

Comment: docker-machine is not docker,  it's just a bunch of script to create virtual machines that will run docker.  The docker command you are running on your MacOS shell is just a client,  it doesn't need any docker to run

Comment: yeah, I know what u means. In fact, I didn't create any virtual machines, but do run my spring-boot app on the "alpine-oraclejdk8" image, so does that mean I exactly using the docker?  And the reason I want to find the virtual machine is I used "nsenter" to enter the container to debug the log of my app but it doesn't work(the writer of "nsenter" told that I need enter the virtual machine first). So this is my confusing point that how the docker is running but I cant find the virtual machine on MAC